# Are both of them grammatical?

Tags: grammar

I want to know if both of the sentences are grammatical or not:

1. I prefer not to end this.
2. I prefer to not end this.

Comment: You don't mean "true". You mean "syntactically valid". And they're both valid.

Comment: I would use the first version only.